# Meet locals in Edinburgh

Tags: sightseeing

I can't remember if it was in Edinburgh, but I think I read about a program, where volunteering locals show tourists around. Does such a thing exist and what's it called? I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You could look here: [Where can one meet other Travel.SE members?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/where-can-one-meet-other-travel-se-members) a number of Travel.StackExchange users have put our names down as being willing to meet people if they are around and free. If you ask nicely some may give a tour.